# Soft Close Drawers

Tags: drawers

I have brand new soft close kitchen drawers.  However they are very hard to pull out and they do not close very well.  Can this improve with usage? Or could they be installed wrong?

Comment: Can you read a manufacturer name? Or post a picture? There are cheap drawer glides that will never be nice, and there are nice glides that are misadjusted...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's very common. They do loosen up after a while, so just work them often for the meantime. However, if there's any kind of grating types of sounds, then there's an installation or defective slide issue. They may be tough to operate, but they should still be smooth & silent.